# Looking for interactive map visualization software that allows user input

Tags: web-mapping, visualisation

I am looking for a software tool that allows to create maps which can be customized by the user later on. To be more concrete: the user should be able to choose different indicators, create his own aggregate scores, attach weight to the indicators and so on. One example is the OECD better life index, it contains these features (you can choose which indicators you want to include, you can weight them, etc). Do you know such a visualization program? The well known ones like Geocommons, ArcGIS, Spatialkey, etc. do not have these features.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Stephanie

Comment: Do you need this software to be available online, as a web app?

Comment: Yes, that would be best. But a software tool that needs to be downloaded or installed at the clients computer would also help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/solutions/mapping). It's been a while since I use it, but it's essentially a data warehousing / Business intelligence sort of software.

I remember from the dw cube you are able to easily create maps from different "dimensions" , criteria, weights and so forth from the data source of your choice. Then the user is able to generate a map, pdf, html, report from it.

There is a free trial available if you want to try it out.